# Confused about Composite Indexes and FFS

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, indexing

I've been reading a lot about Oracle indexes and various types of index scans, notably fast full scan (ffs).  My question will be about the performance of a ffs regarding different index definitions.  I'll describe what I *think* I know about index construction and fast full scan because chances are, I have holes or mistakes in my understanding.

Oracle's indexes are typically backed by a B-tree, where the branches are pointers to a sorted range of keys.  The keys generated are dependent on the columns specified by the index.

If I have an index on columns (A, B), then in sorted order, some leaf nodes might look like this.  The key is column A sorted first, then column B sorted.  Each of the keys point to some row id in the table.

```
A1-B1 -> rowid 5
A1-B1 -> rowid 7
A1-B2 -> rowid 12
A1-B3 -> rowid 24
A2-B3 -> rowid 123
A2-B3 -> rowid 2412
A2-B3 -> rowid 241
A3-B1 -> rowid 234
A3-B2 -> rowid 213
```

Assuming we have 2 branches, the branches might contain the following data

```
Branch 1:
Range: A1-B1 to A2-B3
Children Leaf nodes with row ids: [5, 7, 12, 24, 123]

Branch 2:
Range: A2-B3 to A3-B2
Children Leaf nodes with row ids: [2412, 241, 234, 213]
```

Look ups should just be a simple binary search.

About fast full scan: I understand that if a query only selects columns contained by the index, then we do not need to look at the table.  The index acts as a miniature/skinny table, i.e. we can query the index directly without ever having to look up the table.  As long as the query does not have an ORDER BY clause, we can scan the index using fast full scan.  I believe fast full scan simply looks picks up multiple blocks and filters by whatever selector clause we have.

Finally here are my questions:

Consider two indexes X and Y:

```
X is an index on columns (A, B)
Y is an index on columns (A, B, C)
```

I assume the following SQL should be executed with a ffs for BOTH X and Y index.

```
select count(1) from table where A in (a1, a2) and B <= b';
```

Is there a performance difference during ffs for both of the indexes?
Does index Y perform "slower" because the SQL has predicates only on A and B?

I'm also wondering what "multi block reads" mean.  What is a block?  Is it a section of leaf nodes?  Using the example above, are all of branch 1's leaf nodes a block and all of branch 2's leaf nodes another block?  Is this a multi threaded, divide and conquer read? i.e. each thread reads their own block and aggregrate the results?

Thanks!

Comment: A "block" is simply the smallest logical unit with which Oracle works with its data. You can find more info from the docs: https://docs.oracle.com/html/A96524_01/c03block.htm

Comment: Thanks! Will look at the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The index tree looks like you wrote only when the index is unique.

In most cases the optimizer picks the index X, simply because its size will be smaller - contains only two columns. If the indexes are big and the difference in amount of data scanned is big as well you will notice the difference.

Block is the smallest data unit in Oracle database. The default size is 8 kb (range 2 kB - 32 kB), every data object (like index) in Oracle consists of segment -> extents -> blocks. So all root, branches and leafs of the index are stored in blocks. If the number of entries is small the root block is the leaf block and there are no branches. So in bigger scale is your description correct.

If the scan is parallel, the extents are consecutive ranges of blocks so it's not a problem to define sub-ranges so the processes don't share the same data.

Multi-block read is typical when data isn't needed to be read sorted so you can read many blocks (close to the wanted) with the same effort as one, like your example query where you just count.

Comment: Oops sorry, I wasn't clear. We don't have X and Y index created at the same time.  So I was wondering what the performance of using X would be vs using Y.  The blocks and multiblock reads make sense.  Thanks!

Comment: In the single case you described for just full scan of the index the difference shouldn't be big.

Indexing is very wide area, as with most of the things it depends what do you want to achieve. There are usually pros and cons. It depends on many things, if you aim to use the index more for lookups or as you mentioned the skinny table version, how much is the table modified. Also the order of the columns in the index is important.

Comment: Well here is my question in another way.  I was told that if we originally have index X, the SQL runs pretty quickly.  But if we update X to Y (add C to the index), the SQL performs slower.  I don't understand why this is true and why the SQL would perform slower.

Comment: Depends on SQL and many other things.

For instance,

if many values from column A and B are nullable and you add column C to the index, the index will be bigger because it will contain more rows.

if the values in column C are often updated then the index maintenance will be involved.

Also depends on size of the column C, if the A and B are few bytes and C hundreds the index will be much bigger too.

Comment: Why would there be more rows?  I assume more rows means more leaf nodes and potentially more branches?  I thought the leaf nodes were a 1 to 1 mapping with a row in a table.  So I thought the number of leaf nodes should be the same for both index X and Y

Comment: B-tree index contains only entries when at least one column is NOT NULL. So if many rows in the table have NULL values in column A and B there are not included in the index at all. If the column C is not that sparse all the rows where A IS NULL and B IS NULL and C IS NOT NULL will be added to the index.

Otherwise your assumption is correct.

Comment: Cool thanks. Assuming, column A and column B are never nullable (no explicit constraint) and column C has a very low cardinality (< 5 distinct values), it seems my particular SQL will perform just as fast regardless of whether I use index X or Y. :) ----

Sorry last question.  How would a key be built if some of the columns were nullable and how will this affect sorting? I understand if all the columns are NULL, then they do not show up in the index.  What if only some of the columns are NULL?  Does Oracle treat NULL as the lowest value when they are sorting?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89468/discussion-between-husqvik-and-peter1234).